# Не работает условие внутри цикла

Tags: python, циклы, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Пытаюсь найти количество случаев, когда элемент одномерного массива больше следующего и предыдущего. (Количество поворотных точек при проверке модели)

```
a = np.array(df2['Et'])
print(a)
> [ 1.50840909 -0.30263636 -1.17034848 -0.77472727 -0.28577273  0.06984848
0.41213636  0.47109091  0.36671212 -0.00433333 -0.29037879]
for i in a:
if i>i+1 and i>i-1 or i<i+1 and i<i+1: 
    p=p+1
print(p)
```

Выводит 11 (это количество элементов)

Comment: если вы используете оба операнда `AND` и `OR`, то надо правильно расставить скобки

Comment: А в чем смысл условия `i<i+1 and i<i+1`? :) вместо `p=p+1` используйте `p += 1`. А проверка должна быть кольцевой? т.е. как работает проверка для первого элемента и последнего?

Comment: какой должен быть правильный ответ для приведенного в вопросе `a`?

Comment: Нет ну серьезно,скачайте сначала любой учебник по питону и прочитайте первые 5 глав,а потом сюда с вопросами

Comment: @TEA, на счет `Vanilla Python` согласен, а вто для того чтобы хорошо освоить `Numpy` - одного учебника может не хватить... ;)

Comment: поправил, теперь выводит 0, как раньше. Должно выводиться 2. i>i+1 and i>i-1) or (i<i+1 and i<i-1) не работает и ([i]>[i+1] and [i]>[i-1]) or ([i]<[i+1] and [i]<[i-1]) тоже

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение в стиле Pandas:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
          Et
0   1.508409
1  -0.302636
2  -1.170348
3  -0.774727
4  -0.285773
5   0.069848
6   0.412136
7   0.471091
8   0.366712
9  -0.004333
10 -0.290379

In [31]: res = ( ((df.Et > df.Et.shift()) & (df.Et > df.Et.shift(-1))) 
               | ((df.Et < df.Et.shift()) & (df.Et < df.Et.shift(-1)))).sum()

In [32]: print(res)
2
```

PS исходил из того, что `df2['Et']` - является столбцом Pandas DataFrame

---

решение циклом:

```
In [41]: sum(((a[i] > a[i-1]) & (a[i] > a[i+1])) | ((a[i] < a[i-1]) & (a[i] < a[i+1]))
             for i in range(1, len(a)-1))
Out[41]: 2
```

**NOTE:** всегда старайтесь использовать векторизированные функции методы Pandas / Numpy / SciPy если это возможно. Для больших массивов данных скорость может отличаться на несколько порядков...

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: Не подскажите как через цикл реализовать?

Comment: @DmitryCh, у меня рука не поднимется реализовывать через цикл то, что можно реализовать векторизированным способом в Pandas ;)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сравнивать элемент с предыдущими/последующими, можно использовать `zip`:

```
a = [1.50840909, -0.30263636, -1.17034848, -0.77472727, -0.28577273,  0.06984848,
     0.41213636,  0.47109091,  0.36671212, -0.00433333, -0.29037879]

# Сзипливаем вместе список "a" и пару его копий со сдвигом в один и в два элемента
zipped = zip(a, a[1:], a[2:])

p = 0
for (previous, current, after) in zipped:
    if (current > previous and current > after) or (current < previous and current < after):
            p += 1

print(p)
```